# How do I configure function keys and Fn on a ThinkPad Edge?

Tags: hardware, thinkpad

I have problem with functional keys.

When I want <kbd>F1</kbd> I must press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>. I want to change to press only <kbd>F1</kbd>. Under <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> i would have the functional key (now is mute)

Comment: I don't remember enough to have a full answer, but check the bios, iirc there are settings for the Fn key in there.

Answer (score 2):

BIOS I would say would be your best bet

Comment: Reuben is correct. You'll find the option in the BIOS (hit enter on startup).